# General Email Template

Tags: html, codeigniter, html-email

Does anyone know where I could or how to develop an email template?

I am looking to have the following sections:

`header body footer`

I have tried googling but I have seen some in tables and some in html.  Do I just create it using inline `div & css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly disagree with the answer by @Dzek Trek. When creating html emails i never use divs, and the only css i use is inline css. I say this with 6 months experience building emails.

An example of my overall email layout would be:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="600">
      YOUR CONTENT. Start with a table
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</table>
```

This will center the email inside the email client and will also correct any outer spacing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the wide range of email clients and varying support for CSS rules, it's best to stick to tables when creating HTML emails. Campaign Monitor (http://www.campaignmonitor.com/) have some great resources (including examples) on HTML email best practices.

Answer (score -1):

Well, yes for graphical layout you could use html5 and css3. Here is an example of it

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{blog_title}</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>{blog_heading}</h3>

{blog_entries}
<h5>{title}</h5>
<p>{body}</p>
{/blog_entries}
</body>
</html>
```

And if you want to make it more user friendly and eye pleasent, you could make css file and declare the output of every html element as you like it.

Parsing values is achieved by the following example

```
$this->load->library('parser');

$data = array(
          'blog_title'   => 'My Blog Title',
          'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading',
          'blog_entries' => array(
                                  array('title' => 'Title 1', 'body' => 'Body 1'),
                                  array('title' => 'Title 2', 'body' => 'Body 2'),
                                  array('title' => 'Title 3', 'body' => 'Body 3'),
                                  array('title' => 'Title 4', 'body' => 'Body 4'),
                                  array('title' => 'Title 5', 'body' => 'Body 5')
                                  )
        );

 $this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);
```

You could declare inline elements, but for better handling and less code, declare it externally, in some css file and call it in the html file.

Comment: Well, first part is to make somefile.html file in which you will store all the elements of the web module or page you are about to create. In the second file, named somefile.css you can define the attributes of the elements invoked by somefile.html. Also, would you be more specific what gives you troubles about tables?

Comment: I just like everything modular I guess and it just gets confusing :)  Is there any special was to echo php variables into the view?